# Notify UI update in AppDelegate (UITabBarController badge)

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

In my app, UITabBarController is an initial ViewController build in storyBoard. I would like to observe data updating in my whole app. So I add an observer in appDelegate...

AppDelegate.m

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shipCountBadge:) name:kShipCountBadge object:nil];

- (void)shipCountBadge:(NSNotification *)notification{
Groups *vc = [[Groups alloc] init];
[vc addBadgeCount:notification.object];
}
```

Group.m

```
- (void)addBadgeCount:(NSNumber *)count{
NSLog(@"d",[count intValue]);
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[count intValue]]];
}
```

Its doesn't change the UI at all. I would like to know how to update UI in AppDelegate actually? Anyone has an idea :)?

Comment: Did you post a notification when value changes?

Comment: yes, It look like this > [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNewShipNotification object:ship userInfo:userInfo];

Comment: Does `kShipCountBadge` and `kNewShipNotification` has the same string value?

Comment: sorry, I paste the wrong code. It should like > [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kShipCountBadge object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[list shipCount]]];